# Query across mysql and redshift different database and different servers

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, mysql-workbench

I have a  MySQL in local linux server I want to join and query with amazon redshift. Any possibilities to querying across MySQL and redshift?

Comment: Redshift supports federated queries, but this is just an option if the db is an RDS - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/federated-overview.html

Comment: Thanks,But I want the Mysql table as a locale because of most of the tables available in Mysql.

Comment: Simple - its not possible. Alternate - Export the data into RedShift and do the process. Or  external UDF via Lamba(yeah it's difficult to do this)

Comment: [jlew\_data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11336501) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68658837) saying "Does this help? I don't know if this is what you are looking for... [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cross-database-overview.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cross-database-overview.html)"